# Unable to install Ubuntu to my fresh HP laptop

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation, hp

I have tried installing Ubuntu from both CD and a bootable usb device. But in both cases it doesn't even show the option to boot. It directly goes to my default DOS os. I am sure that I have arranged the boot priority orders in boot menu settings. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try with boot menu option - one of the "Functuion" keys, depends on the computer model and make. Then select manually the bootable media - USB or DVD. The boot menu displays all available boot devices.

Comment: I have already tried the priority of bootable media in boot menu options. My laptop model is HP pavilion r007tx. Could you please tell me to manually select the bootable media while it boots up?

Answer (score 0):

On HP laptops made prior to about 2008, such as the DV9000 I have here, instructions should appear in the lower left corner, instructions which may advise pressing **F9 for a boot menu and F10 for CMOS setup**.

On HP laptops made after about 2008, such as the DV6 I was asked to look at last week, things get a bit more complex.  By default NO instructions are issued on the screen at boot time, unless you **repeatedly tap the ESC key after turning the computer on.  From there you might get a boot menu, or you might see instructions for further F-keys to press for a boot menu or to configure the CMOS setup.

In last week's ordeal even after I got to that screen, I was unable to boot to the desired external USB medium because that laptop appears to require UEFI be installed...  I've learned that since then.  I have installed UEFI onto that external medium and I'm hoping to try it on the DV6 the next time its owner and I can meet up.  She's very interested in Ubuntu.  As demonstrations go, I've had better days.

Comment: How this UEFI thing can be installed? Do you have any link or something for that?

Comment: I doubt this will help you because most likely the bootable USB device you are using is merely a CD image written to USB solid state media.  Such images are typically no designed to be altered, so my guess is you cannot install UEFI onto it.

What I am using, described in the "About Me" section of my user bio permits installing UEFI.  If what you are using is similar:
1) Boot a different computer to the Ubuntu bootable USB media you wish to use.
2) Open a terminal and copy paste the following:
3) sudo apt-get install efilinux

I can offer you guidance to safely make what I have made.